# Do the capabilities of EC2 instances scale proportionately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Say I have three options:

| Instance type | vCPU | Memory (GiB) | Bandwidth (Gbps) | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Small | A | B | C | D |
| Medium | 2A | 2B | 2C | 2D |
| Large | 4A | 4B | 4C | 4D |

What are the implications of running 4 small instances vs 2 medium vs 1 large? Is one better or are they the same?

I am very new to all of this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is accurate **within an Instance Type family**. For example, `m5.large`, `m5.xlarge` and `m5.2xlarge`.

Some benefits of using **multiple (smaller) instances** are:

- Distribute instances across multiple Availability Zones (different data centers) to **avoid potential outage time** (it is rare, but can happen)
- If something goes wrong on a single instance, **only a portion of your capacity is lost** rather than losing *all* capacity
- If your application is not capable of **using multiple CPUs**, then running threads on separate instances will perform better than running a single thread on a larger instance
- Instances can be **updated** (eg installing a new version of software) individually, so only a portion of your total capacity is unavailable during the upgrade process, rather than it *all* being unavailable
- You can **test a newer version of your software** on a single instance and monitor it closely to confirm that it is behaving as expected, rather than needing to roll-out changes all at once

The **down-sides** of using multiple instances are:

- **More overhead** having to run operating systems on each instance (so less RAM and CPU is available to the application)
- The application needs to be **designed to run across multiple instances** (typically in a stateless manner)
- A **Load Balancer** is required to distribute the load (assuming you are running a web app)

Comment: That makes sense. Is the overhead significant? Is there some tipping point where you would be able to notice the overhead? Or does this depend on how the application is designed? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The smaller the RAM, the larger the OS takes as a proportion of all memory. It really depends on how memory-intensive your application is. Oh, I should also mention that you'd need to pay for more disks with multiple instances (for the OS and local storage), so that would be a higher expense for multiple, smaller instances.